# Horror Anthology/Review With Robert Englund

Tags: story-identification, movie

Saw this on USA Network (I think) in the late 80s/early 90s. It was either an anthology series or a miniseries reviewing horror movies. It may or may not have been hosted by Robert Englund. What I remember most is that the intro said something like, "There is nothing to be afraid of except your heart, which can stop beating at any moment". Know what it is?

Comment: Did you go through the IMDB for Englund?

Comment: I did and I didn't find it.  It might not be Englund doing the narration I remember.  It might be that a clip of Freddy was being shown during the narration.  My memory is really vague, but I know that line is pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

[Freddy’s Nightmares](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddy's_Nightmares) has Robert Englund and is an anthology horror tv show from the correct time frame.

Comment: Neither of those is it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Nightmare Cafe" is my best guess.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103502/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_94

The timing is right and it was an anthology series.  "Freddie's Nightmares" is also a possible but that was earlier.